# How do you select element of a form required while also displaying the name of select element in the initial box (HTML Only)?

Tags: html, forms, select

I am creating a simple form using HTML and having an issue with form validation.  Im trying to make the word Month, Day, Year appear in the dropdown select box but not allow it to consider the word Month, Day, Year as a valid option.  Please review my code.  It keeps accepting the values as an option when submitting form.

```html
<form>
    <label>
    Birthday:
      <select name="month" required>
        <option value="month" disabled selected hidden>Month</option>
        <option>Jan</option>
        <option>Feb</option>
        <option>Mar</option>
      </select>

      <select name="day" required>
        <option value="day" disabled selected hidden>Day</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>

      <select name="year" required>
        <option value="year" disabled selected hidden>Year</option>
        <option>1990</option>
        <option>2000</option>
        <option>2010</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: Can you specify the problem ? There are no value attributes in option tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<form>
    <label>
    Birthday:
      <select name="month" required>
        <option value="month" disabled selected hidden>Month</option>
        <option value="January">Jan</option>
        <option value="February">Feb</option>
        <option value="March">Mar</option>
      </select>

      <select name="day" required>
        <option value="day" disabled selected hidden>Day</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>

      <select name="year" required>
        <option value="year" disabled selected hidden>Year</option>
        <option value="1990">1990</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

Are you looking for this ?

Comment: Your code helped me to figure out where I went wrong with my coding.  Ill add my code to this thread once I am done recoding.   Thank you!!!

Comment: Just make sure the basics are well understood! :)

Comment: Thank you.  Im still in the learning phase.  I have quite a bit to learn.

Comment: @MichaelBruley If my answer helped you then accept it as answer and do an upvote! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solution...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>User Registration Form</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>


<h2>Signup For a New Account</h2>
<form id="signupForm">
  <label for="first">First Name</label>
  <input name="first" id="first" type="text" placeholder="John" required>

  <label for="last">Last Name</label>
  <input name="last" id="last" type"="text" placeholder="Smith" required>

  <div>
    <label for="male">Male</label>
      <input id="male" name="gender" type="radio" value="male" required>
    <label for="female">Female</label>
      <input id="female" name="gender" type="radio" value="female" required>
    <label for="other">Other</label>
      <input id="other" name="gender" type="radio" value="other" required>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>
    Email:
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
    </label>
    Password:
      <input type="password" name="password" required pattern=".{5,10}" required title="Must be between 5 and 10 characters">
  <div>

  <div>
    <label>
    Birthday:
      <select required aria-required="true" id="birthdaymonth" name="birthdaymonth">
        <option value="" hidden>Month</option>
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
      </select>

      <select required aria-required="true" id="birthdayday" name="birthdayday">
        <option value="" hidden>Day</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
      </select>

      <input type="text" name="birthdayyear" placeholder="Year (ie. 1991)" required pattern=".[0-9]{3}" required title="Must be 4 digits (Ie. 1989)">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="agreed">I agree to the terms and conditions:</label>
    <input id="agreed" name="agreed" type="checkbox" required>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```